# git does not recognize exe file

Tags: windows, git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, github-for-windows

I'd like to upload **NuGet.exe** to github but all exe files are not listed to my local repository.

I did upload `NuGet.exe` file about two weeks ago at another project repo, but now I cannot upload any exe file at all. There is no global `.gitignore` that I specially defined.

below code is my `.gitignore` file.
what am I missing?

```
# Build Folders (you can keep bin if you'd like, to store dlls and pdbs)
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# mstest test results
TestResults

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder 
[Ee]xpress

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# NuGet Packages Directory
packages

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
sql
TestResults
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.Cache
ClientBin
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*.dbmdl
Generated_Code #added for RIA/Silverlight projects

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML

# Windows-specific files
Thumbs.db
desktop.ini
# Mac-specific things (thanks to Michael Aaron Safyan)
.DS_Store
```

**-- EDIT --**

same files under `.nuget/` directory `.config` and `.targets` files are well treated. I can check `git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard` gives `NuGet.exe` is ignored, but I don't know which rule makes it.

Comment: check in which folders is saved the exes, here you have `Bin/` `bin/` an so on ignored.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix // same files (.config, and .targets) in the folder `.nuget/` are well treated.

Comment: In any case check if there is something in `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix // Thanks for the quick reply. but nothing (only commented words) at there. hmm....

Answer (score 81, accepted):

First, you can check if a file is locally ignored ion your repo with [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html):

```
git check-ignore -v -- yourFile
```

Second, you can force to add that file (bypassing any ignore rule):

```
git add -f yourFile
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you answered, but I would like to know which is the cause of ignorance of `.exe` file. whether it's cause of my `.gitignore` or somewhere settings in git.

Comment: @Youngjae that is what `git check-ignore -- yourFile.exe` is supposed to tell you.

Comment: // sorry to hold your leg. but `git check-ignore -- test.exe` gives `test.exe` simply. looks it's fine that git confirms me the file `test.exe` is ignored. but I'm still scratching my head *why* it is ignored....

Comment: @Youngjae try a `git check-ignore -v -- yourExe.exe`: that should display the .gitignore file and the line within that file causing your exe to be ignored.

Comment: WOW! thanks you. `-v` is important! it gives me `C:\User\Me\Documents\gitignore_global.txt : *.exe`. Definitely what I can understand.

Comment: @Youngjae Excellent. It was a global `.gitignore` file, then. Well spotted.

Comment: `git add -f myfile` did not work for me. My exclusion of *.exe was also in gitignore_global.txt. `!myfile.exe` did work though.

Comment: @RobG if you were trying to add `myfile.exe` (which you succeeded to exclude from the `.gitignore`), then the command should have been `git add -f myfile.exe`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 21):

I just put `!NuGet.exe` at first in `.gitignore` file and work perfect for me

Comment: prob not needed (as of 2021) as the `gitignore_global.txt` , that gets created by the Git installer  in the user's documents folder, should already have a rule to ignore `*.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I used TortoiseGit in Windows using Windows UI, navigated to the folder, right-clicked and added the .exe files directly. These added files showed up in SourceTree and I committed them from there.